# Maven- Build script

Tags: maven, unit-testing, gradle

I need to create a build in such a way that, unit test, integration test and performance test can be executed separately using Maven and Gradle.

Acceptance Criteria :

- Seperate Build files (Maven and Gradle) for unit test, Integration test and Performance test.
- The test execution flexible enough to be executed on Demand like

  - Unit test Alone (Default profile)
  - Unit Test & Integration Test (Profile With Integration Test)
  - Unit test and Performance test.(Profile With PerformanceTest)

Comment: Here how should I create the Maven build script so that when I run command like 'mvn test' only the classes that declared under test package should get execute. And when I run the command like 'mvn integration test' the classes under test and integration test package should get executed. Please help in how should I write the maven build script file to accomplish this.

Comment: This is not a site where you can dump work and get it done. Show some effort and the things you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Start reading the documentation:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/
http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html